# Not connect js to html

Tags: javascript, html

When hovering over the picture, hide information about the link that will appear at the bottom left. When adding this script, the image became unclickable. I think the main problem is the incorrect connection of the js file or the execution of this script. I have added the code of 3 files below

```js
openUrl(url: string): void {
  window.open(url, '_blank');
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Roshan Timing</title>
    <script src="eel.js"></script>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/ico" href="/Roshan.ico"></link>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<!-- TIMER -->
  <p class="timer">Timer</p>



<!-- CHAT(INPUT) -->



<!-- created by dankYbat -->
  <div class="about_right">

    <div class="text_wrap">
      <p class="noselect">created by dankYoff</p>
    </div>
<!--Connect js to tage image -->
    <div class="image_wrap">
      <a><img src="github.svg" (click)="openUrl('https://github.com/dankYoff')" width="50"></a>
    </div>

  </div>
</body>



</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use `openUrl(url: string): void` in a `*.js` file, looks like you want to use [TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/). If you want to create a faster vanilla typescript project you can use [vite](https://vitejs.dev/).

Anyway the a solution can be this:

```js
const imgProfile = document.querySelector('#img-profile');
const openUrl = (url) => {
  window.open(url, '_blank');
};
imgProfile.addEventListener('click', () => {
  openUrl('https://github.com/dankYoff');
});
```

```css
.img-profile {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.img-profile img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  object-fit: cover;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.img-profile img:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

```html
<a class="img-profile" id="img-profile">
  <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2022/09/16/13/07/woman-7458584_960_720.jpg" />
</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for you solution but it doesnt want to open link on browser(

Comment: Copy the code in your local it works or you can try on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-lovelace-xtgdvp).

Comment: it started working from the beginning but for some reason in eel it doesn't want to execute this script properly